# Job description clarification

Tags: job-search

I am looking at a job opening for "Application Analyst III". What does the "III" mean, and what is the difference between "Application Analyst I", "Application Analyst II" and "Application Analyst III"? Here is part of the job description:

> Analyst’s primary role will be to create and modify business web applications built using C# Microsoft technologies. Depending on specific job, an analyst will work with the following technologies:
>   SQL Server, .Net Framework, C#, WCF/Web services, SSRS, MS AX Dynamics, JQuery, MVC, HTML5

Thanks!

Comment: I, II, III respectively are moving up in pay, duties, and responsibilities. Specifics would be up to a particular company.

Comment: There's literally no possible way for any of us to know that. Each company can define these differently.

Answer (score 3):

Contact the company and ask them. Job titles like this are totally company specific.